# Permission is granted in settings but is being ignored

Tags: java, android, permissions

On fresh install, when I click the button it will skip everything until

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unable to get Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It is supposed to request a permission, but for some reason the first time I click the button it just gives me the toast, on second try it requests and then goes to the settings where you can enable permission. With the permission enabled it still asks to enable it when you click the button again. I checked in the phone's settings and it is enabled but still asks to enable it on every click except the first. I also have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>` in the manifest. Im on API >23. **I don't know why it is not recognising that the permission is granted, and I also don't know why it doesn't work on the first click.** Any ideas why it is not working? Thanks. 
*I followed this tutorial* http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

```
package com.example.brett.brightness;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static SeekBar seekBar;
    private static TextView textView;
    private static final int SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_PERMISSION_CONSTANT = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING = 101;
    private SharedPreferences permissionStatus;
    private boolean sentToSettings = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    permissionStatus = getSharedPreferences("permissionStatus", MODE_PRIVATE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressText);
    seekBar.setMax(255);




    Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
                    //Show Information about why you need the permission
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                    builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}, SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, false)) {
                    //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                    // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Need Overlay Permission");
                    builder.setMessage("This app needs overlay permission.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            sentToSettings = true;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Overlay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                } else {
                    //just request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}, SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                }


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, true);
                editor.commit();


            } else {
                //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
                proceedAfterPermission();
            }
        }
    });


}


private void proceedAfterPermission() {
    //We've got the permission, now we can proceed further
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We got the Overlay Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Log.d(TAG, "sending message");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrawOverAppsService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_PERMISSION_CONSTANT) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //The External Storage Write Permission is granted to you... Continue your left job...
            proceedAfterPermission();
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
                //Show Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Overlay Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs overlay permission");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();


                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}, SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);


                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unable to get Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Got Permission
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (sentToSettings) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Got Permission
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have found a temporary solution if you just want your permissions to be recognised and do not need to request them in runtime. Right click on your app folder, and select "Open Module Settings". Go to "Flavors" tab and set "Target Sdk Version" to API 22. As far as I know this grants your permissions on installing and running the app. So far, it has worked fine with no drawbacks. I will update this if I have and problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution if you just want your permissions to be recognised and do not need to request them in runtime. Right click on your app folder, and select "Open Module Settings". Go to "Flavors" tab and set "Target Sdk Version" to API 22. As far as I know this grants your permissions on installing and running the app. So far, it has worked fine with no drawbacks. I will update this if I have and problems.